# How can I do console logging of an array or struct using 'hardhat/console.sol'?

Tags: solidity, remix, hardhat, arrays, console

I am simply trying to console.log the array in solidity using 'hardhat/console.sol'

`uint8[3] memory myArr = [1,2,43]; console.log(myArr);`

I am facing below error:

`TypeError: Member "log" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library console).`

Answer (score 1):

The error you are encountering is due to the fact that the console.sol library does not have a function with the name log. To log an array in Solidity, you can use a loop and log each element individually. Here's an example:

uint8[3] memory myArr = [1,2,43];
for (uint8 i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
console.log(myArr[i]);
}

Alternatively, you can convert the array to a string and log the entire string using console.log(abi.encodePacked(myArr)). Note that this method may not work if the array contains non-primitive values.

Comment: Most reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been using `hardhat console` for a while, but I do not remember I had an issue with it except it was used only for single values - not arrays or structs. Please double check the [official documentation](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/debugging-with-hardhat-network#solidity-console-log).

I would also suggest to do a test coverage for your use case, this approach made console log almost redundant. This is [part of docs](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts) which covers this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this issue because the function `log(uint8[] memory)` doesn't exist. Read through the [`hardhat/console.sol`](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/blob/main/packages/hardhat-core/console.sol) implementation to see the available functions.

The simplest way to do what you want is probably to loop over the array, casting each entry to a `uint256`, and call `console.log(value)` (the full signature being `log(uint256)`) for each entry.